# How to work with database specific repositories

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I use SimpleInjector for my C# WinForms application.
I need to decide at runtime which repository to access (Oracle or SqlServer), as this is up to the user which databse he wants to connect to.
Currently I did it like this, which fails as soon as I add a Decorator for the repository.

```
_container.RegisterCollection<IRepository>(
    new[] { typeof(OraRepository), typeof(SqlRepository) });
```

and to distinguish which one to use, I use a provider class like this:

```
    public T GetRepo<T>(bool oracle)
        where T : class
    {
        var instances = _container.GetAllInstances<T>();
        if (oracle)
        {
            return instances.First(i => i.GetType().Name.StartsWith("Ora"));
        }
        else
        {
            return instances.First(i => !i.GetType().Name.StartsWith("Ora"));
        }
    }
```

I don't want to add a decorator for each database. Also, it seems to be not possible, as there is no `RegisterDecoratorCollection` ;-)

And my stomach tells me, to rely on the string-name of the type like shown above is just not right. 
How should this be done correctly?

edit:
more advanced info about usage scenario:

My UnitTest:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
    ... other dependencies ...
    container.RegisterCollection<ICarRepository>(
      new[] { typeof(OraCarRepository), typeof(SqlCarRepository) });
    container.RegisterCollection<ITruckRepository>(
      new[] { typeof(OraTruckRepository), typeof(SqlTruckRepository) });
    _provider = new RepoProvider(container);
}
```

run the test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetRepoTest()
{
    var repo = _provider.GetRepo<ICarRepository>(true);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(OraCarRepository), repo.GetType());

    repo = _provider.GetRepo<ICarRepository>(false);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SqlCarRepository), repo.GetType());

    var repo2 = _provider.GetRepo<ITruckRepository>(true);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(OraTruckRepository), repo2.GetType());

    repo2 = _provider.GetRepo<ITruckRepository>(false);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SqlTruckRepository), repo2.GetType());
}
```

Comment: How is the repository selected? Does the user change from one database to the other while the application is running, or is this determined once during startup (for instance by specifying this in a configuration file)?

Comment: Yes, while it is running. The user can choose to run one analysis on Oracle and the next one on SqlServer, without having to restart the application.

Comment: Furthermore, the data format for processing is the same. oracle or sqlserver data is put into a business entity by the corresponding repository for further processing in the business layer.  @Steven any update with this additional info?

Comment: I'm sorry, it slipped my attention. There's one thing still unclear to me, that blocks me from answering the question, which is, what kind of of other repository interfaces do you have? In your question you stated 1 `IReposository`, but the `GetRepo<T>` implies there are many others. Can you elaborate on that and perhaps show an example?

Comment: @Steven I added my unit test for a concrete example how the code is used at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually not easily answered.

> And my stomach tells me, to rely on the string-name of the type like shown above is just not right. How should this be done correctly?

With your current design, I can imagine changing your `RepoProvider` implementation to something like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> oracle;
private Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> sql;

public RepoProvider(
    Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> oracle, 
    Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> sql)
{
    this.oracle = oracle;
    this.sql = sql;
}

public T GetRepo<T>(bool oracle)  where T : class
{
    Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer> repos = oracle ? this.oracle : this.sql;
    return (T)repos[typeof(T)].GetInstance();
}
```

You can register this as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IRepoProvider>(new RepoProvider(
    oracle: new Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>
    {
        { typeof(ICarRepository), Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<ICarRepository, OraCarRepository>(container) },
        { typeof(ITruckRepository), Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<ITruckRepository, OraTruckRepository>(container) },
    },
    sql: new Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>
    {
        { typeof(ICarRepository), Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<ICarRepository, SqlCarRepository>(container) },
        { typeof(ITruckRepository), Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<ITruckRepository, SqlTruckRepository>(container) },
    });
```

This allows you to apply decorators, without breaking the system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like so many times with your answers on SO or your blog, this is like opening the door to another world ;-)

Comment: Since you are trying to apply decorators to your repositories, you might want to read [this blog post of mine](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) that talks about how entity-specific repository abstractions might be a bad thing, and how they hinder you in effectively applying cross-cutting concerns using decorators.